# How to visualize the pole-polar relationship if placing pole inside the conics?

Tags: linear-algebra, projective-geometry

This problem comes from  R.Hartley & A.Zisserman [*Multiple View Geometry in Computer Vision*](http://cvrs.whu.edu.cn/downloads/ebooks/Multiple%20View%20Geometry%20in%20Computer%20Vision%20(Second%20Edition).pdf) at page 58:
[image]

To my understanding, the polar $l$ dipicted in above figure goes through two points at which tangent lines insect at pole x. The polar is tangent line when x is on the conic.

**My question**: How to visualize polar $l$ when x is inside the conic?

Comment: Why would you put $x$ inside the conic?

Comment: @DavidK : It may not occur in the real circumstance, but  I just seek the answer from a mathematical view.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The pole-polar has the following important property: if point $x$ is on line $l$ then the polar of $x$ contains the pole of $l$.

So, to find the polar of a point inside, take two line passing through $x$, $l_1$ and $l_2$. Find the poles of those lines, $x_1$, and $x_2$. The line through $x_1$, $x_2$ is the polar of $x$.

Comment: Understandable and concise strategy. Thank you! :)

Comment: @Finley: No worries! And now you should also know how to find the pole of a line that does not cut the conic.

Comment: Yeah, take two points on the line, then find polars of these two points. Intersection of the two polars is the pole of this line. How fantastic the duality is!

Answer (score 1):

Here is something I hope that can be useful

[image]

Comment: Great! I can get it more easily combining your figure with orangskid's strategy.

Answer (score 0):

You simply do not visualize any such thing. There are no tangents to the conic from a point inside.